# SELECT statement in while loop isn't working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created the following Select statement which is working fine:

```
SELECT @Block = [Blok], @Year = [Aar] 
FROM [PT99991_Result].[dbo].[Testheader] 
WHERE N = @TestHeaderID
```

The problem is that this `Select` statement is used in a `While` loop where the database can change to another one during the loop. I have tried to modify the statement to the following but it's not working. I have also tried to use `EXEC` which takes care of my problem but then I'm facing a problem with the local variables `@Block` and `@Year` instead.

```
SET @DataBase = 'PT99991_RESULT' --This is only for test!

SELECT @Block = [Blok], @Year = [Aar] 
FROM '[' + @DataBase + '].[dbo].[Testheader]' 
WHERE N = @TestHeaderID
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To capture output parameters from dyanmic sql, use `sp_executesql`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Also a hint: words like these _"isn't working", "not sure what I'm doing wrong", "facing a problem"_ don't mean anything. Be specific about your problem. Post what you did, what you expect, and what happened, including error messages

Comment: FYI `'[' + @DataBase + ']'` is *not* safe from injection. Use `QUOTENAME`. Just like single quotes (`'`) can be escaped in poorly "parametrised" statements, so too can right brackets (`]`) in dynamic statements.

Answer (score 0):

First, generate a T-SQL template like this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT @Block = [Blok], @Year = [Aar] 
                                                FROM [@DataBase].[dbo].[Testheader] 
                                                WHERE N = @TestHeaderID';
```

Then, let's say that the variale `@Datbase` holds your current database name. If it is not extracted from `sys.database` you can perform additional validation to ensure nobody is doing something wrong.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELEFT 1 FROM sys.database WHERE [name] = @Datbase
BEGIN
    ....
END;
```

After the validation, you just replace the database name in the template:

```
SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = REPLACE(@DynamicTSQLStatement, '@Database', @Database);
```

Then, execute the code passing the parameters:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement
                  ,N'@TestHeaderID INT'
                  ,N'@Block INT OUTPUT'
                  ,N'@Year INT OUTPUT'
                  ,@TestHeaderID
                  ,@Block OUTPUT
                  ,@Year OUTPUT;
```

of course on every loop iteration, reset the template.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of while loop, You can go for undocumented stored procedure: ms_foreachdb and execute against the databases and finally apply filter for the specific database.

**Caveat**: Don't use this in production code, because, it uses undocumented stored procedure.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #test(dbname sysname, blok int, aar int)
DECLARE @db_list NVARCHAR(max) = 'DB1,DB2'

EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; declare @blok int, @aar int; INSERT INTO #test SELECT db_name(), blok, aar from [dbo].[Testheader] WHERE N = TestHeaderId;'

SELECT * FROM #test where dbname in 
(
SELECT value FROM string_split(@db_list,',')
)
```